# How to give css to align chat message automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I plan to implement chatting on my website.

And simple search I endup with here [live-chat](http://www.bypeople.com/live-chat/). It's css and html only.

And I placed into my web page. (see picture )

Now it's live but if I want to add new chat then what to do .. Now it's going behind the first one. Help me here

```
<div>
  <div class="live-chat"></div>
  <div class="live-chat"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: Try to add these to your css .chat-history class

.chat-history {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

and .chat-feedback class change like this 

.chat-feedback {
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 80px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 11px;
}

Comment: @MalithMcR Sorry for bad english.. I want another chat window ... I can able to append the chat.. that's not the plm .. I want to chat with another user with another window on the left...

Comment: Simple 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYjWMa#0

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things in my opinion:

1. use `scrollTop()` method to scroll to bottom.
2. or instead of appending the messages just prepend them to see the latest message.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css and duplicate live chat  div like this

```
#live-chat {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    right: 24px;
    float:right;
  padding:5px;
    width: 300px;
}
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYjWMa#0
```

Comment: Can I see a live link to your chat ?  I can help you if you give me a live link to see this

Comment: yeah where is the link ?

Comment: You have a container with fixed width that's the problem. you have to change .container class like this 
.container {
    min-width: 800px;
    margin-left: 81px;
}

or you have to put live-chat div after container div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93687/discussion-between-malith-mcr-and-rosini).